# How to pretty print with System.Json?

Tags: c#, .net, formatting, system.json

Using the new [System.Json from 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.json%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) or the equivalent [System.Json for 4.0 from Nuget](http://nuget.org/packages/System.Json) how do you format the output so it is indented ans spaced in a more readable form?

So this

```
dynamic jsonObj = new JsonObject();
jsonObj.firstName = "John";
jsonObj.lastName = "Smith";
Debug.WriteLine((string)jsonObj.ToString());
```

Outputs this

```
{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Smith"}
```

When I want this

```
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Smith"
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For future reference, the System.Json library in .NET 4.5 (And 4.5 only, not Silverlight) has the [JsonSaveOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.json.jsonsaveoptions.aspx) enumerator, so you can call `ToString(JsonSaveOptions.EnableIndent)` for pretty printed Json.

Answer (score 4):

Unlike with XML, there's there are no options for this in the built-in library.

Mark Rogers wrote a prettifier, available here:

http://www.markdavidrogers.com/json-pretty-printerbeautifier-library-for-net/